# Adding values to a combo element in Visual Studio Extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I'm trying to create a custom visual studio extension.  It involves a toolbar, with a [combo element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb932513.aspx), which I want to populate programatically.

I made the toolbar and combo box in the vsct, but I'm not sure how to get a reference to it in the code and add items to it.

I have this, where do I go from here?

```
CommandID commandId = new CommandID(GuidList.guidExtensionCmdSet, (int) PkgCmdIDList.cmdMyDropdown);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that cmdMyDropdown is the commandId for your dropdown, you then need to create an OleMenuCommand and add it to the OleMenyCommandService.

```
OleMenuCommandService mcs = GetService(typeof(IMenuCommandService)) as OleMenuCommandService;
CommandID commandId = new CommandID(GuidList.guidExtensionCmdSet, (int) PkgCmdIDList.cmdMyDropdown);
OleMenuCommand menuMyDynamicComboCommand = new OleMenuCommand(new EventHandler(OnMenuWorkorderDropdown), commandId);
mcs.AddCommand(menuMyDynamicComboCommand);
```

In your event, you then have to use

```
Marshal.GetNativeVariantForObject(String[] yourValues, OleMenuCmdEventArgs.OutValue);
```

OutValue is the dropdown reference that gets passed.

Read more here: http://dotneteers.net/blogs/divedeeper/archive/2008/07/14/LearnVSXNowPart25.aspx